# Getting MVC4 error in Studio 2010 Pro

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

`File C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft Corporation\NuGet Package Manager\1.5.20902.9026\Modules\NuGet\profile.ps1` cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system.

I would like to piggyback another :
Why does a new MVC4 project not come with a unit test project? It is not letting me check the box for that.

And one more thing : why is it not including the `MicrosoftMVCAjax` scripts in the scripts folder?
I am finding I can write a working `JSON`app with partial views and callbacks if I have this one from an older MVC2 or 3 project.

Thanks!

Comment: Never mind question one, after a restart of Studio, goes away.

Comment: The other two questions stand. I am using Studio Professional 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create check the unit test project check box for the Internet and Intranet project templates.

We are de-emphasizing the use of Microsoft AJAX scripts in MVC templates and instead focusing on the jQuery family of scripts. However, you can still use the scripts if you copy them from an existing MVC 2 or 3 project.

Comment: Thank you. I have made progress to just using the JQuery scripts included in the project, but the coding has been hard. My Complete method for the JSON looks like 
var obj1 = eval("(" + context.responseText + ")");
Div.innerHTML = obj1.Data;  // I want to use jQuery methods to handle the JSON reply.

Comment: I got the jquery.parseJSON call working. For some reason the newer scripts did not like the $Get syntax I had just after it, so that was confusing the issue. I believe I have a 100% MVC4 JSON application now. Thanks